# Как записать список в файл в правильном порядке?

Tags: python, csv

С помощью `pymysql` делаю запрос к базе данных

```
sql = "SELECT {0} from {1}".format(data,table);
cursor.execute(sql)
items =  cursor.fetchall()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `items` вот такие данные. Как пройтись по ним понятно, а как записать в csv - нет.

```
with open(filename, 'w', newline='\n',encoding='utf8', errors='replace') as myfile:
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=';' )
        for key in items:
            lst = []
            for key, value in key.items():
                lst.append(value)
#lst ['000001', 'Игровой диск PEGI 16+', '000001-000021-000025', Decimal('200.00'), Decimal('500.00'), 0]
            wr.writerow(lst)
```

`Writerow` у меня локально заносит как есть, а на сервере порядок абсолютно другой. Запросы идентичные, входные данные тоже. Не пойму в чем проблема

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sql = "SELECT {0} from {1}".format(data,table);
```

У вас не выбран никакой порядок получения данных, если на сервере данные положены в базу в другом порядке, то и выборка будет в другом порядке, хотя запросы и одинаковые. Надо указать ключ сортировки данных при запросе. Например:

```
sql = "SELECT {0} from {1} order by art".format(data,table);
```

Но ещё лучше, наверное, считывать данные с помощью библиотеки `Pandas` (функция `read_sql`), потом вы сможете легко отсортировать данные, отфильтровать, добавить нужные поля и легко записать в файл в нужном вам порядке.